# PreparedStatement set variable in quotes

Tags: java, sql, date, prepared-statement

I have this part of select

```
to_date(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

and set param from java

```
stmt.setString(2, startDate);
```

but my `startDate` is String (2016-07-13 00:00:00) and I need this result

```
to_date('2016-07-13 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I can make this

```
stmt.setString(2, "\'"+startDate+"\'");
```

But I think it is bad practic.

Can I make something like this

to_date('?','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

or

to_date(\'?\','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

or something else?

Answer (score -1):

This is a copy of Oracle [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date,%20java.util.Calendar)):

> ```
> void setDate(int parameterIndex, Date x, Calendar cal) throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Sets the designated parameter to the given java.sql.Date
>   value, using the given Calendar object. The driver uses the Calendar
>   object to construct an SQL DATE value, which the driver then sends to
>   the database. With a Calendar object, the driver can calculate the
>   date taking into account a custom timezone. If no Calendar object is
>   specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of the
>   virtual machine running the application.